# Is taking Ganga's name at the time of death another way to attain liberation from rebirth?

Tags: identification-request, translation-request, moksha, ganga, garuda-purana

From [*"India and Its Faiths: A Traveler's Record"*](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=2zBOzUE3DZ4C&dq=garuda+purana+ganga&q=%22He+who+calls%2C+O+Ganga%21+Ganga%21#v=snippet&q=%22He%20who%20calls%2C%20O%20Ganga!%20Ganga!&f=false):

Page 36:

> He who calls, O Ganga! Ganga! While life is flickering in the throat, goes when dead to the City of Vishnu and is not born again on earth.”

Garuda Purana X, 30 and 79 (Translated by Wood and Subrahmanyam, The Sacred Books of thee Hindus, Vol IX, Allahabad, 1911

Is this a correct citation and translation?

Comment: I can see no words and translations. Quote the verse and translation you want to check. Link only questions are discouraged.

Comment: I have retracted close vote as you have edited the question.

Comment: Wow! downvote for this question. Robotic ad hominem attacks will endanger the continued existence of the board

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, that is not correct citation for at least this part:

> "He who calls, O Ganga! Ganga! While life is flickering in the throat, goes when dead to the City of Vishnu and is not born again on earth.”

The above verse is found in [Garuda Purana, Chapter 9 by Ernest Wood and S.V. Subrahmanyam](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/gpu/gpu11.htm). **So it's IX, 30 instead of X, 30**.

> 30: And the man who, when his life is leaving, contemplates with faith the Ganges, goes to the highest goal.

Translation of [Garuda Purana, Chapter 10 by Ernest Wood and S.V. Subrahmanyam](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/gpu/gpu12.htm) of relevant part is as follows:

> 30: Purified gold should be used, and sacrifice performed with Rikṣa mantras, with the mantra "Pretājayata," and with leaf-vessels.
>
> 79: He whose bones sink in the water of the Ganges within ten days, never returns from the world of Brahma.